# RabbitMQ and em-websocket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, websocket, rabbitmq

I am struggling to work out how I can communicate between rabbitmq and em-websocet.

I want to place a message from a ruby on rails web page on a queue and have the queue handler process the message even if the browser is closed down.  If the browser stays open, I want the results of the queue handler to pass json back to the browser.

I did find [this](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbit-socks) but the github page says it is depreceated.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, you've got a RabbitMQ queue, a way to add items to that queue, something to process items that get added to that queue, and you basically want to notify the browser of progress on that queue.

There are two main ways that you could approach this:

1. As the final action of the queue processor, publish the item/message via a messaging bus to an instance of em-websocket that's listening on that message bus.
2. If you can add features to RabbitMQ, then you could do the publish from within RabbitMQ, as a post-processed hook or something like that. (note, I don't know enough about RabbitMQ to say you can definitely do this).

Alternatively with #1, you could use Pusher.com or similar service to offload the handling of the WebSocket connections. Then, from within your queue processor, you would do the publish call to that services' API.

In the case of using Pusher, if you publish to a channel/socket that no longer exists (has any connections), then the message would just get discarded.

Hopefully this helps. Let me know if you want any help in setting up a basic em-websocket server.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  That was just the sort of guidance I was after